# Emacs - How "package management tool" got installed?

Tags: package, require

In emacs 24.5.1,

`M-x package-list-packages`

shows the list of packages.

My understanding is, below elisp code should be part of my `.emacs`,

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milbox.net/packages" ) t)
```

I do not see/wrote any such elisp code in `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

**Question:**

For given emacs, How to verify/troubleshoot, how package management tool(`package`) got installed?

Comment: The package system is initialized *automatically* after the init file has been processed, so in general you don't *need* such code in your init file (but there are reasons why you might choose to do so, and newer versions of Emacs will actually add a call to `package-initialize` automatically). See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11127109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gnu` source comes pre-configured by default.  It includes everything in the GNU ELPA.

The configuration you've listed is for MELPA, a different ELPA (Emacs Lisp Package Archive).

Comment: What is the url to be added to pick GNU ELPA in `add-to-list` directive?

Comment: @overexchange `C-h v package-archives RET`

Comment: What does `t` signify in `add-to-list` syntax? above. Any resource to read on this

Comment: You can read documentation for any Emacs function like so: `C-h f add-to-list`

Comment: @overexchange you might also be interested in plain ole' `C-h C-h` :-)

Comment: @phils Checked it. But I do not see any information about `t`. Google does not help me.

Comment: `C-h f add-to-list` tells you: "(add-to-list LIST-VAR ELEMENT &optional **APPEND** COMPARE-FN) ... If ELEMENT is added, it is added at the beginning of the list, **unless the optional argument APPEND is non-nil, in which case ELEMENT is added at the end.**". See also `C-h i g (elisp)nil and t`

Comment: emacs.SE is for specific Q & A: one question per post. It is not for a discussion that chains from one question to another. Please post a single specific question.